# Failed building wheel for simplesoap Python virtualenv

Tags: python, python-wheel, pysimplesoap

When installing PySimpleSoap on a virtualenv everything seems to work fine, then I get an error message `Failed building wheel for pysimplesoap` and at the end there is a message `Successfully installed pysimplesoap-1.16`.

Is it an error that can be ignored or should this be solved before I start to use PySimpleSoap?
In this case I do not really get a message of a package that should be installed. 
If it has to be solved, what would be the best way to do this?

```
(currency-converter)johan@johan-pc:~/sdp/currency-converter$ pip install pysimplesoap
Collecting pysimplesoap
  Downloading PySimpleSOAP-1.16.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pysimplesoap
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pysimplesoap
  Complete output from command /home/johan/sdp/currency-converter/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-l0q8rh86/pysimplesoap/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpynogfhy_pip-wheel-:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/pysimplesoap
  copying pysimplesoap/plugins.py -> build/lib/pysimplesoap
  copying pysimplesoap/simplexml.py -> build/lib/pysimplesoap
  copying pysimplesoap/xmlsec.py -> build/lib/pysimplesoap
  copying pysimplesoap/wsse.py -> build/lib/pysimplesoap
  copying pysimplesoap/c14n.py -> build/lib/pysimplesoap
  copying pysimplesoap/helpers.py -> build/lib/pysimplesoap
  copying pysimplesoap/transport.py -> build/lib/pysimplesoap
  copying pysimplesoap/server.py -> build/lib/pysimplesoap
  copying pysimplesoap/__init__.py -> build/lib/pysimplesoap
  copying pysimplesoap/client.py -> build/lib/pysimplesoap
  installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  running install_lib
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  copying build/lib/pysimplesoap/plugins.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  copying build/lib/pysimplesoap/simplexml.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  copying build/lib/pysimplesoap/xmlsec.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  copying build/lib/pysimplesoap/wsse.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  copying build/lib/pysimplesoap/c14n.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  copying build/lib/pysimplesoap/helpers.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  copying build/lib/pysimplesoap/transport.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  copying build/lib/pysimplesoap/server.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  copying build/lib/pysimplesoap/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  copying build/lib/pysimplesoap/client.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  running install_egg_info
  running egg_info
  creating soap2py.egg-info
  writing soap2py.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to soap2py.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing dependency_links to soap2py.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing manifest file 'soap2py.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

  reading manifest file 'soap2py.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  writing manifest file 'soap2py.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Copying soap2py.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/soap2py-1.16-py3.4.egg-info
  running install_scripts
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/soap2py-1.16.dist-info/WHEEL
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  running install_lib
  copying build/lib/pysimplesoap/plugins.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap
  error: could not create 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pysimplesoap/plugins.py': No such file or directory

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pysimplesoap
Failed to build pysimplesoap
Installing collected packages: pysimplesoap
  Running setup.py install for pysimplesoap
Successfully installed pysimplesoap-1.16
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Hi @MuratCorlu No, I did not find a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a similar thing when trying to use pysimplesoap with Travis CI. A colleague of mine tracked down the problem and raised the issue on [pysimplesoap github](https://github.com/pysimplesoap/pysimplesoap/issues/101) .

The problem seems to be that setup() is called twice because its name is being transitioned from soap2py to pysimplesoap. So it looks like it needs to be packaged better to allow it to work with wheels.